# How to get the value of minlines in Vim

Tags: vim, syntax, synchronization

Vim often shows wrong highlight when opening perl files contain pod paragraphs, use command

```
:syn sync minlines=9999
```

can handle this problem.I am curious about the value of minlines,so,which command will show minlines's value of current opened file? I didn't find that in vim reference manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a native command for that. I suggest you to check it out directly in syntax files. For example, about Perl, take a look at **perl.vim**. I am on Arch Linux and this file is available here: `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/perl.vim`. If you go to line 435, you should see this: `syn sync minlines=0`.

Be aware that some syntax files define specific *minlines* rules. In Ruby/Java files, you should be able to call `:echo ruby_minlines` or `:echo java_minlines` respectively. This will not work with Python, PHP or JavaScript.

Finally, if you are ready to sacrifice a bit of performance for better ergonomics, you can add the following command to your **.vimrc**: `autocmd BufEnter * :syntax sync fromstart`

I use it to avoid annoying issues with syntax highlighting. It works great, but Vim will be extremely slow if you try to edit huge files...